# How to open this panel in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

How can I open this panel in WebStorm IDE?

[image: 1]

The panel shows all the HTML tags used in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

> The panel shows all the HTML tags used in the HTML file.

You are wrong. If that would be true it would then show `head`, `meta`, `title` tags as well.. but they are not there.

---

It is called "bradcrumbs" and it shows the path/hierarchy of the HTML tags for the line where the caret is currently located.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.2/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#editor_breadcrumbs

Just type `bradcrumbs` in the Settings/Preferences window and it will show you all places where that word is used so it's easier to locate the right place.

It will be `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Breadcrumbs`. By default they should be showing at the bottom. Make sure to enable them and configure what file types should show it.

[image]